# User Snippet in C++ Line Highlight

Tags: vscode-snippets

I have create a user snippet for driver code in C++. But when I use that code snippet my line gets highlighted. Even though I have other snippets for class, for loops, etc but problem persist only with cpp snippet.

`cpp.code-snippet`:

[image: 1]

`example.png`:

[image: 2]

Comment: It is preferable to publish the code (including snippet code) in text rather than an image :)

Comment: BTW bits/stdc++.h is strongly discouraged, as it is non-standard and clutters the namespace leading to unintended bugs

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet contains one placeholder (`$1`). When you insert a snippet, the cursor gets to the position of the first placeholder and all the placeholder code will be grayed out for your convenience. As soon as your cursor leaves this gray area, the area will stop being gray. In general, you can use the `tab` key, which takes you to the next placeholder, if there is one, and outside the snippet otherwise; if you are inside the placeholder, then you can return to the previous one with the `shift + tab` combination.